# How to use a struct in std::map?

Tags: c++, stl, stdmap

I have a complex struct i want to put as a key of the std::map to make a list of all unique objects fast:

```
union somecomplexstruct {
     struct {
        more_structs val1, val2;
        even_more_structs val3, val4;
        lots_of_more_structs val5;
     };
     unsigned int DATA[3];
};

typedef map<somecomplexstruct, int, greater<somecomplexstruct> > somecomplexstructMap;
```

But it says error: `error C2784: 'bool std::operator >(const std::vector<_Ty,_Alloc> &,const std::vector<_Ty,_Alloc> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::vector<_Ty,_Alloc> &' from 'const somecomplexstruct'`

How do i make my struct work there?

**Edit:** Got it working, thanks to everyone! Heres the code:

```
inline bool operator>(const somecomplexstruct &v1, const somecomplexstruct &v2){
    if(v1.DATA[0] > v2.DATA[0]) return 1;
    if(v1.DATA[0] < v2.DATA[0]) return 0;
    if(v1.DATA[1] > v2.DATA[1]) return 1;
    if(v1.DATA[1] < v2.DATA[1]) return 0;
    return v1.DATA[2] > v2.DATA[2];
}
```

Comment: That definition of `operator>` is not good.  If `v1.DATA = {1,0,0}; v2.DATA = {0,1,0};`, it claims that both `v1>v2` and `v2>v1`.

Comment: Note that, while I have yet a platform where this doesn't work in practice, writing one value to a union and then accessing it as another value technically leads to undefined behavior.

Comment: what do you mean, my code is flawed? how i fix it?

Comment: do you mean about that i should use #pragma pack(1) to ensure the structs wont get padded?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`std::greater<>` invokes `operator>()` to do its work, so you need to overload that if you want to use `std::greater<>`.

It should look like this:

```
inline bool operator>(const somecomplexstruct& lhs, const somecomplexstruct& rhs)
{
  // implement your ordering here. 
}
```

Comment: Hmm, i cant quite get the logic in that function, when i need to only create unique objects list, should i change my map somehow, because this operator > doesnt make much sense. Or does it even matter what i put inside that function, because its only used for sorting, but not for testing if the object is equal to some other object in the list already? So if i want, i could as well just return 1 in that function always? OR does this affect performance or something? I am having hard time creating the test to see if the data is greater than other data.or should i even care if its "perfect"or not?

Comment: I was thinking to make union from the struct, then compare `unsigned int` array values like: `inline bool operator>(const somecomplexstruct &v1, const somecomplexstruct &v2){ return (v1.DATA[0] > v2.DATA[0] && v1.DATA[1] > v2.DATA[1] && v1.DATA[2] > v2.DATA[2]); }` But it doesnt look like a right solution to this... Because not all the bits need to be greater, but if i use || in between `unsigned int` tests, then it also fails... so some help would be appreciated here

Comment: If you don't mind the ordering, and you just need to implement the `operator>` for using the struct within a `std::map`, you can always do a `return(&lhs > &rhs)` instead of the `return 1`. That will order the structs according to their memory layouts.

Comment: Could i as well just return 1 if i dont care about the order?

Comment: @Newbie: `std::map` uses the ordering in order to efficiently determine whether it has a given key in the map. It's normally implemented as a balanced binary search tree. If you can't provide an order, then you could instead provide a hash function and use the non-standard `boost::unordered_map`, or `hash_map` if your C++ implementation offers it. If you can't provide either an order or a hash function, then you can't efficiently test for duplicates, and you might as well just use a `vector<pair<Key, Value> >` and search it linearly.

Comment: @Newbie: the most common way to produce an order is a so-called "lexicographic order". So if struct X contains a Y and a Z, then X's order function is something like `if (lhs.y < rhs.y) return true; if rhs.y < lhs.y) return false; return (lhs.z < rhs.z);`. You can extend this for things with multiple members, and you'll have to define an ordering similarly for any structs contained in the one you care about.

Comment: The reason why im using a struct in the map is because i am afraid of hash collisions :P And since the data size is only 3 times that, i dont see much performance problems different from a hash...

Comment: @Steve Jessop: is there a typo in your code? where is x checks? and shouldnt it be `lhs.y < rhs.y` instead of `rhs.y < lhs.y` ?

Comment: So, should this be ok? `if(v1.DATA[0] > v2.DATA[0]) return 1; if(v1.DATA[1] > v2.DATA[1]) return 1; return v1.DATA[2] > v2.DATA[2];` I made union from the struct and now im comparing unsigned ints from the struct raw data. (note: v1 = lhs, v2 = rhs)

Comment: I tested each of those implementations, and i found out that `if(v1.DATA[0] ...` was the fastest one, and `return (&v1 > &v2)` slowest! it was 4 times slower than the fastest. Even `return 1` was only 3 times slower than the fastest.

Comment: lol, i tried with `return v1.DATA[0] > v2.DATA[0]` and it was 3 times faster than my previous fastest solution :S Am i doing it right?

Comment: Apparently i am doing it wrong, i looked at the size of the map, and the faster versions have less elements added in it. But the `return (&v1 > &v2)` and `return 1` gave same amount of elements, but `return 1` was 30% faster.

Comment: Looks like i am failing hard today, so seems like the whole map doesnt even work in the manner of unique items... its just storing everything in it in both cases `return (&v1 > &v2)` and `return 1` ... help?

Comment: `if(v1.DATA[0] > v2.DATA[0]) return true; if(v1.DATA[1] > v2.DATA[1]) return true; return v1.DATA[2] > v2.DATA[2];` seems to be the correct one(?), i must check it with another method to be sure about the unique items count...

Comment: I made it work with converting the data into string HEX code into string map. i cant get it work any other way, so im still seeking for a struct method for this...

Comment: Most probably you've written a wrong comparator. Search or post a separate question on how to write a comparator for your key structure.

Comment: By the way, `{ return &v1 > &v2; }` is NOT a good comparator.  The `map` can and will make copies of its inserted arguments, and those copies won't compare the same way as the original if their addresses are used, causing undefined behavior.

Answer (score 3):

With your `operator>` function, consider what happens if you compare `{1, 0, 0}` and `{0, 1, 0}`.  If you compare `a > b`, it returns true from the first comparison.  If you compare `b > a` it returns true from the second comparison.  So its fails the reflexive property for comparisons, scrambling the map.  In order for map to work properly, you must define your operator> such that `a > b` == `!(b > a)` for all possible non-equal pairs of values that might be compared.

**edit**

The easiest/best way to ensure that your operator is properly reflexive is to ensure the for every test that might return true, you also have a test with the same condition and the operands swapped that returns false.
So if you have

```
if(v1.DATA[1] > v2.DATA[1]) return 1;
```

in your function, you need

```
if(v2.DATA[1] > v1.DATA[1]) return 0;
```

or the equivalent somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Here is lexicographical comparator for a complex structure

```
struct D {
  struct A {
    bool operator <(const A &) const;
  } a;
  struct B {
    bool operator <(const B &) const;
  } b;
  struct C {
    bool operator <(const C &) const;
  } c;
  template <class T> ne(const T & a, const T & b) {
    if (a < b) return true;
    if (b < a) return true;
    return false;
  }
  bool operator < (const D & that) const {
    if (ne(a, that.a)) return a < that.a;
    if (ne(b, that.b)) return b < that.b;
    return c < that.c;
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll fix consts, and leave members for the sake of shorter declarations.

Comment: I get this error: `error C2678: binary '!=' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const D::A' (or there is no acceptable conversion)` from that struct

Comment: Sorry for that, I applied a quick fix, to prevent this error.

Answer (score 0):

If your map contains only pointers to your struct, you don't have to do all that complicated operator overloading.

Therefore your typedef looks like this:

```
typedef map<somecomplexstruct*, int, greater<somecomplexstruct*> > somecomplexstructMap;
```

Structs typically have only public data members and no need for operator overloading.

This means though that you have to be careful about when and how you release the memory for the pointers. There's pros and cons to each approach, as with everything.